# How to make list view as multiselectable

Tags: android

In screen layout as I declared my list view as

```
 <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
```

And row layout is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

My problem is I want to make my list view as multi selected, but when I add attribute in list view `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` it doesn't work. And one way is there, with java code but when I changed id of listview `android:id="@id/multi_selectable_list` as before `android:id="@id/android:list` then at loding time of layout it gives error.
Is there any way, or in same way I am doing something wrong.
Actually I want multisectable list view, rules are

1. there is a button if I clicked on that list should be change in multiselected.
2. By default list view can not multiselectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this method for being listview multiselect:

---

```
listView.setChoiceMode (int choiceMode);//for multiple choiceMode=2,For single choiceMode=1;for none cj\hoicMode=0;
```

---

Comment: but when list view id as "@id/android:list", how to access that id in my java code. For example if we declare "android:id="@id/multi_selectable_list" then it can be find as findviewbyid(R.id.multi_selectable_list), but when I used "@id/android:list" how can I find that list Id?

Comment: I added my problem in my question. Actually when I changed Id of list view it does not work.

Comment: i think best way to wirte id is @+id/idname,try this it will always work

Comment: these links also be helpful 1. http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/ 2. http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you wish to move from clicking the whole row item to clicking each child element separately, then I think this happens automatically [android 2.1].Try assigning an OnClickListener to each view separately. if you wish to get the row item then get the view's parent by using v.getParent().getParent().

//this is the onItemClick() not in use now

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    t.show();

    Object a = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

    if(a instanceof YourListItem)
        {
            YourListItem yourListItem = (YourListItem) a;

        }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

// this onClick function reconstructs it

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.b_searchSaved)
    {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Search.class));
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.savedRowItemText)
    {
        t.show();

        //there must be some more efficient way to do this
        //i'm reconstructing data from onItemClick to find out position and item [route]
        AdapterView<?> parent = (AdapterView<?>) v.getParent().getParent();

        int position = parent.getPositionForView(v);

        Object a = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        if(a instanceof YourListItem)
        {
            YourListItem yourListItem = (YourListItem) a;

        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```